# need explanation for belongs_to association detailed reference build_association(attributes = {})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :trial_subscriptions
  attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes

end
```

in my trial_subscription.rb

the model is

```
class TrialSubscription < ManualSubscription

end
```

Please note that the ManualSubscription model inherits from the subscription model and this model has a

```
belongs_to :user
```

I am trying to use the `4.1.1.3 build_association(attributes = {})` from the active record guide to build the user. I need some more detailed explanation.

in my rails console I am doing the following and my reasoning for the following

```
@subscription = TrialSubscription.new() #creating a new object
@user = @subscription.build_user(email: 'blahblahblah@gmail.com', password:'eightcharacterslong')#building the user
@user.save #saving the user permanently
User.last #saved user shows up
```

but when I do the following

```
@a = User.last
@a.trial_subscriptions
```

I am getting an empty array.

When I do

```
Trial_Subscription.last, there is no extra record (the TrialSubscription.new ? )
```

I would expect the last trial_subscription record to have its

```
user_id #be filled in with the build user that I just created.
```

some explanation would be great!

these code will be going to my trial_subscriptions_controller.rb and there will be a form posting user inputted information.

Also I just noticed that I can do a

```
@user.trial_subscriptions.create!() #and then maybe a @user.save
```

but I feel like the first way should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your two models first:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trial_subscriptions
  attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes
end

# app/models/trial_subscription.rb
class TrialSubscription < ManualSubscription
end
```

The point of discussion should be your usage of `attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes`, what this does is allows `trial_subscriptions_attributes` for mass assignment.  Now the point to note here is, whichever model you define `attr_accessible :association_attributes` in should be the model you use to create the association.

The next point point of discussion would be around `mass_assignment`.  You have allowed `trial_subscriptions_attributes` for mass assignment, but `trial_subscriptions_attributes` is not a member attribute of the model class `User`.  You have `trial_subscriptions` but not `trial_subscriptions_attributes`.  You could simply define a getter and a setter for `trial_subscriptions_attributes`, but Rails already provides `accepts_nested_attributes_for` helper for doing so for associations.  So update your model `User` to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_subscriptions`:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trial_subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_subscriptions
  attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes
end
```

With this setup you should be able to create user with associated trial subscriptions as:

```
@user = User.new(email: 'blahblahblah@gmail.com', password:'eightcharacterslong')
@subscription = @user.trial_subscriptions.build
@user.save #saving the user permanently

User.last // Shows last user
User.last.trial_subscriptions #shows last users trial subscriptions
```

With the approach you're taking to create users through trial subscription, you need to define `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `attr_accessible` in `trial_subscription` model instead of `user` model.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: this helps a lot, I actually have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `attr-accessible` defined correctly. I didn't know you can do a `User.new` and build the subscriptions instead of doing a `Trial_Subscription.new` and build the user.

Comment: Usually, you want to the other way around, i.e. use model with `has_many` to create the associations, because it's the user that exists first before a he/she can subscribe.  But this does not mean that you cannot do it other way around.

Comment: how can I do this the other way around? I want to build it through user, create a form and have the attributes nested but the user is getting created in the devise registration controller with a registration form. I am having trouble creating two sign up forms in devise. I posted some questions regarding this if you know devise. I may consider building it the other way around instead of doing a user first.